# Количество соединений php curl

Tags: php

Запускаю скрипт в разных вкладках, после 30 вкладки скрипты не грузятся ( вечная загрузка ) как я понял стоит лимит, как его убрать? ( опен сервер )

Comment: Вы запрос к своему или чужому сайту делаете? Есть ещё такая вещь как https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: @Pro100Magistr rtr Браузеры имеют лимит на подключение к одному хосту. Надо настойки менять там. Каким браузером пользуетесь?

Comment: Браузер опера ,,,,-