# ПОМОГИТЕ РЕШИТЬ ПРОБЛЕМУ С PHP

Tags: php

Есть 50 скриптов php которые я паралельно запускаю (опенсервер) но когда я дохожу до 38 скрипта, следущие скрипты не работают ( просто вечная загрузка, возможно стоит в очереди и ждет пока другие скрипты завершат работу чтоб освободить для их место )
Тут дело не в мощности процессоре, по сколько скрипты работают через curl ( по многопоточности не говорите, есть на это причины )))
Так же дело не в лимите конектов браузера, пробовал в разных браузеров по 20 скриптов запускать, все равно после 38 скриптов остальные не запускаются.
Что это может быть и как убрать этот лимит?

Comment: А если первым запустить 38-й, то проблема повторяется?

Comment: Без разницы как их запускать, после 38 запущеных остальные не запускаются

Comment: fiddler + логи ? а так Вам тут не экстрассенсы, что бы ответить на такой вопрос :-)

Comment: смотрите логи, что там есть, и фиддлер, или любой другой снифер, можно даже в хроме в инструментах разработчика вроде посмотреть активность сетевую, что бы посмотреть отправлется ли вообще запрос на сервер

Comment: а так-же смотрите конфиги OpenServera, плюс конфиги которые у него для nginx или апача и для php

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Количество соединений php curl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1086299/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-php-curl)